# Integration tests on SQL Server, setup testing db

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, integration-testing

I develop in asp.net with entity framework and I try to make some integration tests on DB. I use SQL Server Express, which I don't have so much experience with. Even I will use rollback after each test, I want to be sure that my testing DB is always empty before all tests will run. What's the best practice?

In one [Pluralsight video](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/entity-framework-applications-integration-testing) author deletes db files before tests like this:

```
private static void DestroyDatabase()
{
    var fileNames = ExecuteSqlQuery(Master, @"
        SELECT [physical_name] FROM [sys].[master_files]
        WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID('Globalmantics')",
        row => (string)row["physical_name"]);

    if (fileNames.Any())
    {
        ExecuteSqlCommand(Master, @"
            ALTER DATABASE [Globalmantics] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
            EXEC sp_detach_db 'Globalmantics'");

        fileNames.ForEach(File.Delete);
    }
}
```

After that he creates db again. I am wonder why he doesn't use sql command *drop database* instead of deleting files? Maybe *drop database* can be issue with entity framework?

What if db uses filestream? If I am not wrong it's necessary to set filestream manually after new db is created. So far I figure out I can delete only tables and keep empty db with filestream like this:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(500) DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + tc2.TABLE_NAME + '] DROP [' + rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc1
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc2 ON tc2.CONSTRAINT_NAME =rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME

OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
Exec sp_executesql @Sql
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
END

CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
GO

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
GO
```